# Is there a way to get a _stable_ generic class name in Swift?

Tags: swift

Getting the name of a class in Swift is pretty easy like so:

```
import Foundation

class Gen<T> {
    init() { }
}

func printName(obj: AnyObject) {
    dump(NSStringFromClass(obj.dynamicType))
}

let a: Gen<String> = Gen()
let b: Gen<Int> = Gen()
printName(a)
printName(b)
```

However if you **run the above code twice**, it will not produce the same result.

So is there a way to implement `printName` (get at a specialized generic class's name) in a stable way? That is multiple runs of the code prints the same string for the same class?

I'm using the latest Xcode beta.

Some extra requirements:

- The number of classes that will be passed to `printName` is high.
- There maybe more than one generic class, but not a lot.

Comment: What is the application for keeping the same output?

Comment: Mostly for verification of stored data. Being able to do `NSClassFromString()` would be nice, too but not required.

Comment: Is T required to be "Any"? If so, what types are you expecting? (This is easily solvable for T: AnyObject)

Comment: @Reflejo AnyObject or even NSObject is fine. I'm dealing with proper classes. No structs or primitives. Although that'd be nice.

Comment: Why do you want to test against the "dynamicType" ? What do you realy want to know?

Comment: @Alex Think of it as writing a method that accepts `x: AnyObject` if you don't do `x.dynamicType` all your types are gonna end up being `AnyObject` regardless of whatever `x` you are given.

Comment: Clarified the question a bit just in case.

Comment: @chakrit perhaps this helps a little. I partly work around this problem by using something like this (Playground Code) func unsafeGetTypeId(type: Any.Type) -> uintptr_t {
    return unsafeBitCast(type, uintptr_t.self)
}
func areOfSameType(v1: Any, v2: Any) -> Bool {
    return unsafeGetTypeId(reflect(v1).valueType) == unsafeGetTypeId(reflect(v2).valueType)
}
class Gen<T> {
    init() { }
}
class Generator {
    func generate<T>( v: T ) -> Gen<T> {
        return Gen<T>()
    }
}
var generator = Generator()
var g1 = generator.generate("String")
var g2 = Gen<String>()
areOfSameType(g1, g2)//true

Comment: Ups, I didn't notice that this question rise a problem specific to Swift. Since in Swift you have _Access Control_ (i.e. `private`, `internal`, `public`), strictly speaking you have to deal with the case of class name clashing, due to same name but in non colliding _access area_. Reasoning the Obj-C way this would not happen, and I suppose this is the case of you project needs. But I just figured out that, strictly speaking, in Swift this could be something to care about.

Comment: @perifly good point. hadn't thought about that. but surely it should be possible to do. Apple just didnt have the time to be doing it yet.

Comment: Since this is for verification, is the identity of a class required to be persistent across multiple launches of the application? Because, as @MarcoPashkov has rightfully pointed out in his answer, this is *currently* not possible.

Comment: **run the above code twice** should already implies that, no?

Comment: Now that XC6.3b1 is out, how should I reward the bounty now? Should I reward the bounty to @Roman since he seems to have put forth the most effort?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**New starting from Xcode 6.3 beta 1**

Good news! Starting from 6.3 you can do:

```
toString(Gen<Int>())
```

And that'd print: `Gen<Swift.Int>`

**OLD Answer:**

If the scope can be reduced to T: AnyObject then you can implement it as follows:

```
class Gen<T: AnyObject> {
    var className: String {
        return "Gen<\(NSStringFromClass(T.self))>"
    }
}
```

Comment: Well it works, but only for `Gen`. Also I have about 3-4 generic classes that I needed this on. A protocol-based approach might be nice. Don't really want to be hitting another compiler bug though. Protocols are just buggy : (

Comment: I apologize - I tried to edit my code and mistakenly changed something in Reflejo's code and I'm not sure how to fix it. Hopefully the peer review will catch it and reject my change.

Comment: Peer review didn't catch it, so I re-edited it to put it back the way it was. Again, sorry for messing with your answer. Wait! Someone fixed it, but I only saw if after I re-edited it! I feel like I'm stuck in some bizarre recursive loop....

Comment: @chakrit Check my edit, starting from 6.3 you can do it with no hackery.

Comment: Saw it on HN this morning then came on the answer haha.

Answer (score 7):

Sorry to disappoint, but this does not seem to be possible, unless you actively write a new compiler.

Check this [source](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2014-08-01-exploring-swift-memory-layout-part-ii.html) out. The author describes it quite well: `Note that the isa pointer of the two objects is not identical, even though both are an instance of WrapperClass. Evidently, a specialization of a generic class is a separate class at runtime.`

What I was also playing around with was `@objc`, but this is just changing the namespace of the class, but obviously has no influence on the class name.

Answer (score 2):

This will print `Gen` and will work for any class as far as I can tell:

```
class Gen<T> {
    init() { }
}

func printName(obj: AnyObject) {
    let desc = reflect(obj).summary

    let scanner = NSScanner(string: desc)

    var name: NSString?

    scanner.scanUpToString(".", intoString: nil)
    scanner.scanString(".", intoString: nil)
    scanner.scanUpToString("", intoString: &name)

    if let n = name {
        println(n)
    }
}
```

But, it won't give you the specialized type - `Gen<String>` or `Gen<Int>`, for example - and I'm only testing it right now on the online REPL, so results may vary inside a project or a playground.

Do you need it to give the specialized type, or is the class name sufficient?

EDITED: I combined @relejo's answer and mine to give you the specialized type, using a protocol and the computed property that he suggested:

```
protocol GenericClassName {
    var className: String { get }
}

class Gen<T: AnyObject>: GenericClassName {
    init() { }
    var className: String {
        return NSStringFromClass(T.self)
    }
}

func printName<U: GenericClassName>(obj: U) {
    let desc = reflect(obj).summary

    let scanner = NSScanner(string: desc)

    var name: NSString?

    scanner.scanUpToString(".", intoString: nil)
    scanner.scanString(".", intoString: nil)
    scanner.scanUpToString("", intoString: &name)

    if let n = name {
        println(n + "<\(obj.className)>")
    }
}

let gen1 = Gen<NSString>()
let gen2 = Gen<NSNumber>()

printName(gen1) // Outputs: Gen<NSString>
printName(gen2) // Outputs: Gen<NSNumber>
```

EDITED AGAIN: On second thought, if you are going to be adding a computed property to each generic class (you say you only have 3-4 of them, right?) then just make it look like this:

```
class Gen<T: AnyObject> {
    init() { }
    var className: String {
        return (reflect(self).summary.componentsSeparatedByString(".").last ?? "") + "<\(NSStringFromClass(T.self))>"
    }
}
```

Now you can get the class name as a string like this:

```
let gen1 = Gen<NSString>()
println(gen1.className)    // Output: Gen<NSString>
```

That way you aren't messing with protocols or global functions or `NSScanner` (which can be slow...).

Comment: Wow, that's a pretty long answer. Thanks! : ) I don't think `printName` should _enforce_ the `GenericClassName` protocol, though. That means that all classes have to implement it, not just the generic ones.

Answer (score 1):

Building off of the top answer, if you just want the actual class name, not including the "module" it is in, just split by "." and get the last element of that array. I needed to grab the generic's name to write a generic core data function so as to be able to call *NSManagedObject.insertObjectIntoContext* so I'm not calling *NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject...* all over the place.

Code:

```
func insertNewObjectIntoContext<E>(moc: NSManagedObjectContext) -> E {
    return NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(toString(E).componentsSeparatedByString(".").last!, inManagedObjectContext: moc) as! E
}
```

The part of interest to this question is:

```
toString(E).componentsSeparatedByString(".").last!  // returns E - rather than ModuleName.E
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this could be a hint toward the solution you are looking for:

```
class Gen<T> {
    init() { }
}

enum ClassID: String {
    case GenInt = "Gen<Int>"
    case GenString = "Gen<String>"

    func classFromID(stringID: String) -> AnyClass? {
        if let classID = ClassID(rawValue: stringID) {
            switch classID {
            case .GenInt:
                return Gen<Int>().dynamicType
            case .GenString:
                return Gen<String>().dynamicType
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

In short, build your own class ids, and the relative functions to get them back. You preserve security since if a class is not a *known* class, it will not be used.

Comment: I think I might have short of 100 possible values of `T`. it's an internal serialization framework. Modifying `Gen` to emit hints is definitely possible, though.